# VBA and XML quick search of childnode index

Tags: excel, xml, vba

Is there any possibility to extract childnode index without loop.

The problem is a have specified query, **which cannot be modified** to the company database. 
Script will return results in XML format.

The problem is that this specified query, returns more than 10,000 nodes, with 30 childnodes each. This gets multiplied by 100.

Is there any possibility to locate and set the index of a node based on the fact, that im searching for index with childnode that I know value for.

Looping, unfortunately, takes quite some time, and I wanted to make it a bit faster.

In Summary:
I want to Index the location of node row, where element1 has a value = "element1.3".

Return false if such element does not exist.
If exist go extract from this node, element2, and element3.

This is an example, in real code, I want to extract more values from this row.

```
<row>
 <element1>elementone</element1>
 <element2>elementtwo</element2>
 <element3>elementthree</element3>
</row>
<row>
 <element1>element1.2</element1>
 <element2>element2.2</element2>
 <element3>element3.2</element3>
</row>
<row>
 <element1>element1.3</element1>
 <element2>element2.3</element2>
 <element3>element3.3</element3>
</row>
<row>
 <element1>element1.4</element1>
 <element2>element2.4</element2>
 <element3>element3.4</element3>
</row>
<row>
 <element1>element1.4</element1>
 <element2>element2.4</element2>
 <element3>element3.4</element3>
</row>
```

regards, 
KM

Comment: have you looked into xpath?

Comment: Unfortunately, i didn't locate function of XPath that would suit those need, but its possible that im doing something wrong. 

What i had tried to do: set row = domdoc.SelectNodes("/row[element1='" & "element1.3" & "']")  where "element1.3" is between & & as this is not a constant value and i use declared string to search for it. But this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get an XML node index**

> *"Is there any possibility to locate and set the index of a node based on the fact, that im searching for index with childnode that I know value for."*

As the question in OP actually asks to *quick-search a node **index***, I demonstrate a way how to get the (1-based) index number via a XPath query. As you know you can reference each nodename by its position number (index number) directly, e.g. the third row via `//row[3]`.

I assume that the `row` tag follows immediately to the document element in hierarchy (comparable roughly to the `<html>` tag in a web document structure).

**Example call**

```
Sub TestNodeIndex()

'[0]declare xml vars/objects
    Dim xFile   As String: xFile = "rowsindex.xml"  ' <<  change to your needs
    Dim xDoc    As MSXML2.DOMDocument60             ' <<  reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0
    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60             ' set early bound xml doc object instance to memory
'[1]load xml file
    If Not xDoc.Load(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\" & xFile) Then
        MsgBox "XML File not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
'[2]find (first) occurrence of a row node where child node element1 has a text value of 'element1.3'
    Dim xRow As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Set xRow = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("row[element1='" & "element1.3" & "']")
'[3]show 1-based index of found node (0 = not found)
    Dim pos As Long: pos = NodeIndex(xRow, "row")
    Debug.Print "Node index = " & IIf(pos, pos, "N/A")
End Sub
```

Note that you can change the above example's sections `[2..3]` which assume a *single node selection* easily to a loop over a whole `NodeList` set.

```
    Dim xRows As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set xRows = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("row[element1='" & "element1.3" & "']")
    For Each xRow In xRows
        Debug.Print NodeIndex(xRow, "row");
    Next xRow
```

**Help function `NodeIndex()`**

```
Function NodeIndex(curNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode, Optional ByVal tag = "row") As Long
'Purpose: get node index of current node
'Method : count preceding nodes adding current node (+1)
'a) escape if nothing found
    If curNode Is Nothing Then NodeIndex = 0: Exit Function ' if no search result
'b) return node index as function result
    NodeIndex = curNode.SelectNodes("preceding-sibling::" & tag).Length + 1
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that may actually help with another issue I'm having :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Xpath, indeed seems to do the trick.

Before i was using below code:

```
set row = domdoc.SelectNodes("/row[element1='" & "element1.3" & "']")
```

Where the correct one supposed to be, as row is a parentnode:

```
set row = domdoc.SelectNodes("//row[element1='" & "element1.3" & "']")
```

This will in fact return only rows, that contain subchildnodes that i need.

Comment: That will indeed set a node list of your row nodes (alternatively: `Set xRow = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("row[element1='" & "element1.3" & "']")`); but didn't you ask to get the current **index** number of the found node(s) in your post?

Comment: The double slash only indicates to search at any node hierarchy including the document element without referencing the document element explicitly :-)

Comment: Yes, at first I had wanted to extract index and set to it, but I was grasping straws with that. I thought there is no way that I can set them by childnode value, and this was just an idea that i had to resolve that.